# Changing VkBuffers used in command with out re-building the command buffers?

Tags: glsl, gpu, vulkan

This might be an X Y problem, so here's my issue:

I'm trying to send a command buffer to the GPU that adds values to a shader buffer, eg:

```
#version 450
#define INPUT_ARRAY_SIZE 1024
layout(std430, binding = 1) buffer InputArray{
    float array[ ];
}input_array;

void main() 
{

    uint index = gl_GlobalInvocationID.x;
    if (index >= INPUT_ARRAY_SIZE){
        return; 
    }
    InputArray.input_array[index] += 3;
}
```

I would like to be able to swap out the `VkBuffer` I use to back the shader buffer with other buffers.  ie:

```
void addValue(device, queue, command_buffer, buffer);
```

or

```
void addValue(device, queue, command_buffer, descriptor_set);
```

where I would swap out buffer for other buffers I want to add values to.

Unfortunately I don't see a way to do that with out re-recording my command buffer.   As far as I can tell my only options for minimizing the command buffer impact (which is large when my invocations take nano seconds), is to use secondary command buffers, and use pipeline cache some how.  Otherwise I would have to create a command buffer for every single new buffer, which is not feasible when I have more than 100 commands. It doesn't seem to be possible to use [`VkUpdateDescriptorSets`](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/issues/69) with out re-recording as well.

Is there a way to use pre-recorded command buffers, and change the `VkBuffer` used behind the shader buffer at will with out re-recording the command?

Answer (score 1):

Not without [the EXT_descriptor_index extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/html/chap44.html#VK_EXT_descriptor_indexing). Descriptor values (the location of the GPU resources they represent) are supposed to be baked into the CB at write time, not read from some external source.

Even with descriptor index, you need to ensure that the CB is not being executed before you can update the descriptor. So that would require a GPU/CPU sync (which may or may not be bad, depending on your semaphore/submission code structure).

> Otherwise I would have to create a command buffer for every single new buffer, which is not feasible when I have more than 100 commands.

You should not put each command in its own buffer. You should bundle as many commands together as possible.

In general, the cost of building command buffers is pretty low. Coupled with threading their construction, they shouldn't be your primary concern here. Especially when the number of commands is as low as "more than 100 commands;" Vulkan users routinely issue *thousands* of commands into CBs repeatedly, every frame.

Comment: I believe there is a misunderstanding of what I was talking about when I said 100 commands.  These commands are akin to add, subtract, divide multiply etc... basic array operations.  I have no clue when and in what order these will take placem. I'll have 100s of seperate un-related buffers that need the operations done on them, which means I'm creating a 100 commands for each *and I don't even know if I'll need them*.  Alternatively, I create the command everysingle time I run one of these operations, but considering these are one time commands, that seems a bit of a waste.

Comment: additionally, I'll be creating command buffers virtually every single time I run a command in a lot of situations if I don't pre-record.  If I need to run add 1000 arrays independently, that means I need 1000 command buffers *created*, not even submitted.  If I need sin, same thing.

Comment: @opa: "*If I need to run add 1000 arrays independently, that means I need 1000 command buffers created*" Why can't you put them all in the same command buffer? It seems to me that the main problem is that, whatever you're trying to do, you're doing it wrong. But I don't know what you're trying to do, so I can't speak to that. "*considering these are one time commands*" But they're not "one time commands"; they're acting on the same memory.

Comment: "they're acting on the same memory" No, they aren't, that's the whole point of the question, *I'm doing the same operation but on completely different sets of memory*

Comment: @opa: Right, that was the typo. My point is that the same operation *isn't the same* if it happens on different memory.

Comment: wait then what did you mean to say then?  To me I saw that as "they aren't one time because they are operating on the same memory" but the way you worded this reply it sounds like you meant the exact opposite of that, could you clarify?  I'm getting the impression now that what you mean to say is "operations on different memory should be different commands because of how commands are designed, thus ignoring extensions, you *should* be recording new command buffers if you change the memory involved, that's how the API was designed to function"

Comment: @opa: Operations on different memory *are* different commands, not "should be". That's what my answer is saying. The sentence should have been "they're not 'one time commands'; they're acting on ***different*** memory". That's why I keep telling you to just build your command buffer data as you get operations to perform.

Comment: Okay, can you add an explanation to why operations on different memory are necessarily different commands to your answer?

Comment: @opa: It's the *second sentence* of my answer.